# how to remove parent and make child as parent

Tags: jquery, parent-child

This is my code; I want to remove the parent one. What do I need to change?

```
var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

moveUp = function(obj2, height, paused){
    if(paused) return;

    var obj = obj2.children('ul');
    first = obj.children('li:first').clone(true);

    obj.animate({top: '-=' + height + 'px'}, options.speed, function() {
        $(this).children('li:first').remove();
        $(this).css('top', '0px');
    });

    if(options.animation == 'fade') {
        obj.children('li:first').fadeOut(options.speed);
        obj.children('li:last').hide().fadeIn(options.speed);
    }

    first.appendTo(obj);
};
```

Comment: what you want to achieve? what is "parent one"?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking, but from the sound of your title you're looking for `unwrap()`: http://api.jquery.com/unwrap